# How to extract nested tag from this JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have the following MediaWiki JSON format.
How would I go about extracting the content of the 'extract' tag, when underneath the pages I have a tag with a page number that keeps changing?

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "warnings": {
    "extracts": {
      "*": "1"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "2205": {
        "pageid": 2205,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Name",
        "extract": "Body"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this code it works:

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data['query']['pages']['2205']['extract'];
```

But again, given the page id keeps changing, I can't get it working properly.
I've tried:

```
echo $data['query']['pages'][0]['extract'];
```

, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) to get the first element of an array:

```
$page = reset($data['query']['pages']);
echo $page['extract']; // Body
```